# Referencing to unnumbered sections does not work

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, unnumbered-sections

I have unnumbered sections in my appendix to which I want to refer to specifically.
As the sections are unnumbered, it always just shows the number of the chapter.

My example code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xr-hyper} %for cross-referencing between documents
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\begin{document}

\chapter{Main Document}

Here I refer to appendix \ref{Appendix_1}, appendix \ref{Appendix_2} and appendix \ref{Appendix_3}.

\chapter{Appendix}
\section*{A.1 Appendix 1}
\label{Appendix_1}

My first Appendix.

\section*{A.2 Appendix 2}
\label{Appendix_2}

My second Appendix.

\section*{A.3 Appendix 3}
\label{Appendix_3}

My third Appendix.

\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I already tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48610/234353 but that did not work.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: The `\label`/`\ref` always references the last stepped *counter*. Since starred sections are unnumbered, the `\label`s all refer to the chapter. Why do you use unnumbered sections if you want to reference them?

Comment: Because I don't want the appendix to be numbered in the toc.
Is there a way to adjust the counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `\label` always points to the last stepped reference counter, so using unnumbered sections cannot work. If you only have one appendix I would use the following dirty trick

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,openany]{scrbook}% a5,openany only for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Main Document}
\section{Foo}
Here I refer to appendix \ref{Appendix_1},
appendix \ref{Appendix_2} and appendix \ref{Appendix_3}.
\section{Baz}

\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} % remove sections from ToC
\addchap{Appendix} % unnumbered but printed in ToC
\refstepcounter{chapter} % necessary for working bookmarks
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
\section{Appendix 1}
\label{Appendix_1}
My first Appendix.

\section{Appendix 2}
\label{Appendix_2}
My second Appendix.

\section{Appendix 3}
\label{Appendix_3}
My third Appendix.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I actually found another workaround with **[hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280464/234353)**